# Span in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, span

I have one question about the span thing in linear algebra.

So I got this linear solution, 
(x1,x2)=t*(-2,1)

But when I have to write the 'span', can I just pick any number for t, such can I write, span for t=-1, so the solution is,
span(2,-1)

or the span is just the vector which is being multiplied by t, therefore will it just be, 
span(-2,1)

Which one is the correct one? Thanks for the help :D

Comment: You can pick any (real) number for t, as long as you avoid choosing zero.

Comment: @A.Sh doesn't a span include the zero vector?

Comment: Yes, the zero vector is included in the span. I thought your question was about what values of t you could use to generate the span. Note that span(0)={0}, since any multiple of the zero vector is zero. However, span(-2,1)=span t(-2,1) for any nonzero (real) value t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that the span of $(-2,1)$ is the line $\{t(-2,1):t\in\mathbb R\}$; that is, a vector generates its span.